# SimpleCursorAdapter and event auto loadmore ( load data on scroll )

Tags: sqlite, autoscroll

i'm use English very bad, so it is very difficult to describe the problem below. bothered everyone : ) : )

I have a code below:

```
String sql = "select * from " + MySQLiteOpenHelper.tb_name
                + " where " + MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_id_atm + " > 0 and "
                + MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_id_atm + " <= 300";
cursor = dataHelper.SELECTSQL(sql);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_id_atm));

            String Bank = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_bank));
            String Address = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_address));
            Log.d(TAG, "id: " + id + " Bank: " + Bank + " address: "
                    + Address);
        }
String[] from = { MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_bank,
                MySQLiteOpenHelper.cl_address };
        int[] to = { R.id.tvBank, R.id.tvAddress };
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AtmActivity.this,
                R.layout.item_atm_layout, cursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Yo, i'm need use AutoLoadMore to solve this problem ( 300 rows, load very stupid o.O ), and how to do that?
Thanks !